# Why change in CommandTimeout not working

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have MVC2 application using Entity Framework and ADO.net. In ADO.net SqlCommand connection, it get,

Server Error in '/' Application.
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The code is,

```
using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    var commandText = "exec 'stored producedure name'";
    command.CommandTimeout = 240;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(commandText, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Table");
}
```

The stored procedure takes about 3 mins to complete. So I change CommandTimeout to 240s (4 mins) from default 30s. However it still gets "Time out" error after about 30 second running. It looks look CommandTimeout is not working. The code runs in VS 2010. How to change the command timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout you set here is the timeout for the driver you use. Maybe you have a timeout setting in your SQL server itself. Open the SQL management studio, connect to the SQL server and right click on properties to check under options if you set another timeout there. Set it to your prefered value there.